# Django full text search: says unaccent does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

I am using Django 2.0 and postgresql 9.6

I have created and empty migration file in my app (articles) with the following content to add unaccent and trigram extensions

```
# Generated by Django 2.0 on 2018-02-06 22:34

from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import UnaccentExtension, TrigramExtension


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('articles', '0012_auto_20180205_2234'),
    ]

    operations = [
        UnaccentExtension(),
        TrigramExtension()
    ]
```

Then i try to run the following query:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchRank, SearchVector
vector = SearchVector('title',config='unaccent', weight='A') + SearchVector('description',config='unaccent', weight='B')
query = SearchQuery('india')
Article.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query)).filter(rank__gte=0.3).order_by('rank')

ProgrammingError: text search configuration "unaccent" does not exist
LINE 1: ...rticle"."qa_bool", ts_rank((setweight(to_tsvector('unaccent'...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your migration file haven't created the specified PostgreSQL extension in your database.

Maybe your database user don't have superuser privileges.

The Django documentation explain it in section [Creating extension using migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#creating-extension-using-migrations):

> Creating the extension requires a database user with superuser privileges. If the Django database user doesn’t have superuser privileges, you’ll have to create the extension outside of Django migrations with a user that has the appropriate privileges. In that case, connect to your Django database and run the query `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;`

## Update

I read again your code and I think the problem is `config='unaccent'` you can't use `unaccent` as a config but you have to pass a language (es: 'italian') or 'simple'

Comment: The user i am using has superuser privilages. I checked that.

Comment: To be sure try the query suggested by the documentation 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXIST unaccent;'

Comment: So where should i mention about unaccent

Comment: Try to update your question explaining the desired results of your query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230566/using-unaccent-with-searchvector-and-searchquery-in-django: As per this answer you have gave should i have to create an unaccented dictionary.