# django full text search: how to do with accent text

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

I am using Django 2.0 and postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1

I am having the below model with headline and body_text:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The below is my content

```
headline: Dhṛtarāṣṭra inquired from Sañjaya,

body_text:
Prabhupāda: So Dhṛtarāṣṭra inquired from Sañjaya, kim akurvata: "After my sons and my brother's sons assembled together for fighting, what did they do?" This was the inquiry. So to encourage him... Because Sañjaya could understand the feelings of his master that he wanted the fight, no compromise, kṣatriya spirit, "Let my sons and my brother's sons fight..." That is kṣatriya spirit.
```

Also i have installed unaccent extension in the following way:

```
# Generated by Django 2.0 on 2018-02-06 22:34

from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import UnaccentExtension, TrigramExtension


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('articles', '0012_auto_20180205_2234'),
    ]

    operations = [
        UnaccentExtension(),
        TrigramExtension()
    ]
```

Extension got installed successfully. Now i want to search for accented word Dhṛtarāṣṭra. So i am trying the following:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchRank, SearchVector
vector = SearchVector('title__unaccent', weight='A') + SearchVector('description__unaccent', weight='B')
query = SearchQuery('Dhrtarastra')
Article.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query)).filter(rank__gte=0.3).order_by('rank')

: Cannot resolve keyword 'unaccent' into field. Join on 'title' not permitted.
```

I have read here: [Using unaccent with SearchVector and SearchQuery in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230566/using-unaccent-with-searchvector-and-searchquery-in-django): that

> You can't use 'unaccent' in 'SearchVector' but you have to define a
>   new "unaccented" config in PostgreSQL.
>
> Create your unaccented dictionary in PostgrSQL or using an empty
>   migrations with this SQL:
>
> CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION french_unaccent( COPY = french );
>
> ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION french_unaccent ALTER MAPPING FOR
>   hword, hword_part, word WITH unaccent, french_stem;

Here `COPY = french` is used. In my case which dictionary i should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the dictionaries supported by PostgreSQL:

- Simple
- Danish
- German
- English
- Spanish
- Finnish
- French
- Hungarian
- Italian
- Dutch
- Norwegian
- Portuguese
- Romanian
- Russian
- Swedish
- Turkish

You can verify it from [PostgreSQL source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/bin/initdb/initdb.c#L664).

Comment: In my case should i use simple or english.

Comment: Yes. If you want for example to match similar words and removes articles and your text is in English I think you have to use 'english' . If you want to match exactly the words in your text you have to use 'simple'.